# Editing and merging xml files without modification of input files

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0

My task is to merge two xml files together. Before merging these two files, I need to remove the first line of the second file. I was able to receive the needed output file by writing these two lines:

```
#case if both files exists - remove first line from the file
(Get-Content $JfilePath | Select-Object -Skip 1) | Set-Content $JfilePath

#mergeFiles together
Get-Content $MfilePath, $JfilePath | Set-Content $mergedFile
```

The issue is that I am modifying the second file by executing the first cmdlet. I would like to keep both files in original form. I dont want to also create any temporary files.
I was trying to perform the following:

```
 Get-Content $MfilePath, (Get-Content $JfilePath | Select-Object -Skip 1) | Set-Content $mergedFile
```

but I received the error:

```
Get-Content : Cannot convert 'System.Object[]' to the type 'System.String' required by parameter 'LiteralPath'. Specified method is not supported.
```

Could you please help how the output file could be received without modifying these input files?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
(Get-Content $MfilePath), (Get-Content $JfilePath | Select-Object -Skip 1) | Set-Content $mergedFile
```